# Asus TUF graphics card problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 23.04, nvidia-geforce

when I installed the system my graphics card was disabled using Armory Crate in Windows. Now, if you turn it on in Windows, and then go into Ubuntu, it will envy after entering the user. I assume that the computer is trying to start the video card, but does not have the necessary drivers, and it is impossible to install them with the card turned off
A vicious circle has formed - to install the driver, you need to turn on the video card, to turn on the video card and log into the system, you need a driver

Asus TUF Gaming A17 FA706IH
Geforce GTX1650

Comment: What happens in Ubuntu if you run `sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot` ?

Comment: A look at this ? https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/asus-a17-tuf766iu